# square summable sequence multiplied by square root

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a square-summable sequence (of real numbers), is it true that

$$\sqrt{n} x_n \rightarrow 0$$ ?

Here are my thoughts:

- I know that the sequence $1/n^\alpha$ is summable if and only if $\alpha > 1$. Hence, for every $\delta > 0$ the sequence $n^{-\frac{1+\delta}{2}}$ is square-summable.
- I know also that (square-)summable sequences are null-sequences.
- With these two facts I was able to show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a square-summable seqences $(x_n)$ for which $n^{1/2 + \epsilon} x_n$ does **not** converge to zero and conversely, that $n^{1/2 - \epsilon} x_n$ **does** converge to zero for every $\epsilon >0$ and every square-summable sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let
$$
a_n=\begin{cases}0&\text{if } n \text{ is not a perfect square,}\\
\dfrac1k &\text{if }n=k^2.\end{cases}
$$
The sequence $a_n$ is
$$
1,0,0,\frac12,0,0,0,0,\frac13,0,0,0,0,0,0,\frac14,\dots
$$
Then $\sum a_n^2<\infty$ but $\sqrt{n}\,a_n=1$ if $n$ is a perfect square.